# variable value not updating in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, subscribe

```
export class Test implements OnInit {
    getRoleTypeValuesArray:any = [];
    array = [];
    constructor(private ls: myService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
      this.ls.testApi().subscribe(y => {
            this.getRoleTypeValues = y;
            this.getRoleTypeValues.map(y=>{
                var obj = { value: y.id, label: y.roleName }
                this.getRoleTypeValuesArray.push(obj);
            });
            this.array = this.getRoleTypeValuesArray;
            console.log("test1:",this.array);
        });
        console.log("test2:",this.array);
    }
}
```

I am getting values in `test1` console, but not outside `test2` console. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong wtih your code; that is how asynchronous code works:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @Amy thanks, it is working. I can take `this.array` value further!